# Filter actor touch from screen touch

Tags: android, libgdx, actor, stage, scene2d

I have a game with a virtual joystic and I also implement ontouch and onDraged to move the camera. I want the camera to stand still and stop moving/zooming when the touch belongs to virtual joystic. Is there any better way than checking if the click is between x coordinates?

Comment: have you tried with libgdx [TouchPad](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Touchpad.html) class?

Comment: yep, I'm using libgdx TouchPad, then I add it into stage (I read it on a tutorial), then I have to deal with the stage and my own "world" but the TouchPad is moving along with the camera

Comment: When using the various listeners, onTouch and so on, there's a boolean return value which denotes whether the touch has been handled or if it should continue to some other inputhandler. Do you use this, or do you just return false? Please show some of the relevant code.

Comment: I return true but, how can I controll which listener is called first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When using the various listeners, onTouch and so on, there's a boolean return value which denotes whether the touch has been handled or if it should continue to some other inputhandler. Do you use this, or do you just return false? Please show some of the relevant code. –  TobLoef 9 hours ago

Thanks to his comment and doing some test, to filter touches, inputListener from touchpad must be the first I add into input multiplexer:

```
InputMultiplexer inp = new InputMultiplexer();
inp.addProcessor(stage);
inp.addProcessor(new InpListener(this));
inp.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestListener(this)));
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inp);
```

That way I can return true if the touch belonged to stage, handle it otherwise.